# field is Integer and I am getting PDOException error thrown

Tags: 7, entities

I have a field called "blog_post_guid" and it is set as Integer.

Recently, it is throwing this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of
>   range value for column 'blog_post_guid_value' at row 1: INSERT INTO
>   {field_data_blog_post_guid} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id,
>   bundle, delta, language, blog_post_guid_value)

Running a search revealed this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1003692).

Based on this information I thought I should install and enable BigInt.

Is there any other relevant solution to this issue for Integer field and Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

Using [bigInt](https://www.drupal.org/project/bigint) module is the best way for achieve this job, there is another solution like altering database table but it not recommanded

Comment: I was looking at this code to accomplish the migration(?)  http://cgit.drupalcode.org/helper/tree/lib/FieldChangeHelper.php?h=7.x-1.x

Comment: @fndtn357 your welcome